# How to zoom a sheet in revit api?

Tags: revit-api

I wrote an external command that creates detail views for doors, windows, etc and puts each object in a separate sheet.

Sometimes the new sheets are zoomed-out by default (the yellow circle shows the actual sheet).
I guess it has to do with the witness lines (in the blue circle).

[Sheet zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iier2.jpg)

I tried activating the views and then found their uiView and used the zoom methods but they don't seem to make a difference (possibly because they work in model coordinates and not in sheet outline coordinates).

uv.ZoomToFit();

Manual zoom-to-fit works fine.
Also, the sheet's outline property is correct (not too large).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ShowElements method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/52ac2a55-1397-3d05-311f-de3443421ae6.htm) to zoom to an element. That does the same as zoom-to-fit to a specific set of elements. The element may possibly also be the sheet itself.

[The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) discusses how that can also be used to [Switch View or Document](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/03/switch-view-or-document-by-showing-elements.html).

Also, look at [displaying a text file from a `TaskDialog` command link](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/10/uiview-windows-coordinates-referenceintersector-and-my-own-tooltip.html#22).

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, ShowElements would also switch to the new sheet, which isn't what I'm looking for (as I create a bunch of sheets and I don't want to show them all). I figured I'd do it using the OnViewActivated event when a new sheet is displayed. This works well. Thanks!